# Where is the implementation for FMT_API auto vformat(string_view fmt, format_args args) -> std::string;?

Tags: fmt

I can see the declaration for `vformat(string_view fmt, format_args args) in` [core.h](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/9.1.0/include/fmt/core.h).

```
FMT_API auto vformat(string_view fmt, format_args args) -> std::string;   //line number 3190
```

But I can't find the implementation for said funciton after I have carefully searched and read the project.

I only can see the declaration and implementation of `fmt::v9::detail::vformat(const Locale& loc, basic_string_view<Char> format_str, basic_format_args<buffer_context<type_identity_t<Char>>> args)` in [format.h](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/9.1.0/include/fmt/format.h), but it not what I am looking for.

```
template <typename Locale, typename Char>
auto vformat(const Locale& loc, basic_string_view<Char> format_str,
             basic_format_args<buffer_context<type_identity_t<Char>>> args)
    -> std::basic_string<Char> {
  basic_memory_buffer<Char> buffer;
  detail::vformat_to(buffer, format_str, args, detail::locale_ref(loc));
  return {buffer.data(), buffer.size()};
}
```

Comment: And what are you looking for exactly ? The real logic of `fmt::vformat` seems to be implemented in internal functions like `detail::vformat_to`.

Comment: @HubertGruniaux I am looking for the implementation for `fmt::v9::vformat(string_view fmt, format_args args)` whose declaration could be seen in core.h. The `detail::vformat_to` is called in `fmt::v9::detail::vformat(const Locale& loc, basic_string_view<Char> format_str, basic_format_args<buffer_context<type_identity_t<Char>>> args)` other than `fmt::v9::vformat(string_view fmt, format_args args)`.

Comment: @HubertGruniaux See my answer below. Is it the one(`detail::vformat_to`) which you mentioned defined in  [format-inl.h](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/9.1.0/include/fmt/format-inl.h)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is implemented in [format-inl.h](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/9.1.0/include/fmt/format-inl.h)

```
FMT_FUNC std::string vformat(string_view fmt, format_args args) {
  // Don't optimize the "{}" case to keep the binary size small and because it
  // can be better optimized in fmt::format anyway.
  auto buffer = memory_buffer();
  detail::vformat_to(buffer, fmt, args);
  return to_string(buffer);
}
```